# XML ERROR in Workbook Setting REASON: Too many tags

Tags: xml, plsql, export-to-excel, oracle-apex

I have created a PL/SQL procedure to generate excel spreadsheets (in XML format) those are downloadable from an Oracle Application Express (Apex).

However,

When one generate a second file when the first one is still open in Excel then it gets the following error message:

```
XML ERROR in Workbook Setting
REASON: Too many tags
FILE:   C:\...
GROUP:  Workbook
TAG:    Worksheet
ATTRIB: Name
VALUE:  Sheet1

XML ERROR in Workbook Setting
REASON: Too many tags
FILE:   C:\...
TAG:    Worksheet
ATTRIB: Name
VALUE:  Sheet2

XML ERROR in Workbook Setting
REASON: Too many tags
FILE:   C:\....
GROUP:  Workbook
TAG:    Worksheet
ATTRIB: Name
VALUE:  Sheet3
```

I think it is related to the "Worksheet" tag. However, the issue cannot always be replicated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

Make sure you're not trying to name more than one worksheet with the same name.

Open the xml document in a text editor and do a search for (e.g.) "Sheet1" if you find the line

```
 <Worksheet ss:Name='Sheet1'>
```

in more than one place then your procedure is generating duplicate worksheet names.

Comment: Thx buddy, this was exactly mine problem and your suggestion solved it!